# Extraer url de un video directo del cdn con javascript o php?

Tags: php, javascript, css3

A ver les comento. Tengo un proyecto de una pagina para ver series. La cosa es que actualmente los videos que tenemos los pasamos directo por el iframe que nos da el servidor (Openload, rapidvideo, etc)

Todo se hace mediante una llamada a la base de datos que tiene almacenado el codigo iframe.

Posteriormente hacemos el display con una concatenacion en un elemento tab de bootstrap. Les comparto codigo para que se hagan una idea.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">

            <?php 

                $id = $_GET['Id'];                  
                $nombre = $_GET['StrNombre'];

                try{
                    include"bin/core/conexion.php";

                    $sql="SELECT capitulos.Id,capitulos.StrNombre,capitulos.StrOpcion1,capitulos.StrOpcion2,capitulos.StrOpcion3,capitulos.StrOpcion4,capitulos.StrOpcionD,capitulos.StrImagen,capitulos.IdRel FROM capitulos INNER JOIN series ON capitulos.Idrel = series.Id WHERE capitulos.id='".$id."'";
                    $resultado= $base->prepare($sql);
                    $resultado->execute(array());
                    if($crow=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        echo"
                        <ul class='nav nav-pills nav-fill' id='pills-tab' role='tablist'>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a id='pills-o1-tab' data-toggle='pill' href='#pills-o1' role='tab' aria-controls='pills-o1' aria-selected='true' class='nav-link active rounded-0' style='color:#ebcc34;'>1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a id='pills-o2-tab' data-toggle='pill' href='#pills-o2' role='tab' aria-controls='pills-o2' aria-selected='false' class='nav-link rounded-0' style='color:#ebcc34;'>2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a id='pills-o3-tab' data-toggle='pill' href='#pills-o3' role='tab' aria-controls='pills-o3' aria-selected='false' class='nav-link rounded-0' style='color:#ebcc34;'>3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a id='pills-o4-tab' data-toggle='pill' href='#pills-o4' role='tab' aria-controls='pills-o4' aria-selected='false' class='nav-link rounded-0' style='color:#ebcc34;'>4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='nav-item'>
                                <a id='pills-o5-tab' data-toggle='pill' href='#pills-o5' role='tab' aria-controls='pills-o5' aria-selected='false' class='nav-link rounded-0' style='color:#ebcc34;'>Descargar</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            <div class='tab-content' id='pills-tabContent'>
                                <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 tab-pane fade show active' id='pills-o1' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='pills-o1-tab'>
                                    ".$crow['StrOpcion1']."
                                </div>
                                <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 tab-pane fade' id='pills-o2' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='pills-o2-tab'>
                                    ".$crow['StrOpcion2']."
                                </div>
                                <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 tab-pane fade' id='pills-o3' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='pills-o3-tab'>
                                    ".$crow['StrOpcion3']."
                                </div>
                                <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 tab-pane fade' id='pills-o4' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='pills-o4-tab'>
                                    ".$crow['StrOpcion4']."
                                </div>
                                <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 tab-pane fade' id='pills-o5' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='pills-o5-tab'>
                                    <a class='rounded-0 btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block align-self-center' href='".$crow['StrOpcionD']."'<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span>Descargar Capitulo</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        ";
                    }

                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        echo "Fallo en la base datos" . $e->getMessage();
                    }


                ?>
                </div>
```

La cosa es que quisiera empezar a usar un reproductor diferente al que ofrecen los servidores antes mencionados. Ya hice pruebas y encontré uno muy bueno llamado [Plyr](https://plyr.io/) que usa como base el reproductor HTML5 por defecto.

La cosa es que ese metodo requiere la url directa del cdn, que suele terminar en .mp4 o .webm

Una solucion seria ir video por video, tomar la url directa, y reemplazarla en cada serie. la cosa es que ese proceso es engorroso y demorariamos muchisimo tiempo ya que son muchos los videos que habria que procesar.

Entonces mi pregunta. De la url que ya nos proporciona el servidor, por ejemplo

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.rapidvideo.com/e/G0FNBNBU6K" frameborder="0"marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Como podría sacar con javascript, o con php, realmente no se cual seria mas adecuado para la tarea, lo que es la url directa, como ejemplo una como esta:

```
https://tr1jhcxujk.playercdn.net/186/0/2gMIj1SpLnvrOvJxPT8RcA/1552021288/190222/714G0FNH42I47VMJW2PE2.mp4
```

y agregarla automaticamente al elemento correspondiente de video.

Comment: Entiendo que $crow['StrOpcion1'] contiene el código html del iframe, en este caso, con php puedes usar la librería simple_html_dom.php para cargar el iframe en un objeto y con find buscar el src, Tienes la documentación en http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm

Comment: Gracias!. Al final funciono de maravilla. Lo que hice fue agregar el siguiente codigo `require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
       $url = $crow['StrOpcion0'];
       $html = file_get_html($url);
       foreach($html->find('source') as $element)`